# How to use beautiful soup find function to extract html elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to pull the table corresponding to the HTML code below

> ```
> <table class="sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="team_pitching" data-cols-to-freeze=",2">
>     <caption>Team Pitching</caption>
> ```

from https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=17cdc2d2. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjhOJ.png) of the site layout and HTML code I am trying to extract from.

I was using the code

```
url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=17cdc2d2'
res = requests.get(url)
soup1 = BS(res.content, 'html.parser')
table1  = soup1.find('table',{'id':'team_pitching'})
table1
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this working. The table above can be extracted with the line

```
table1  = soup1.find('table',{'id':'team_batting'})
```

and I figured similar code should work for the one below. Additionally, is there a way to extract this using the table class "sortable stats_table now_sortable" rather than id?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you open the page normally it shows all the tables, however if you load the page with Developer Tools just the first table is shown. So, when you do your request the left tables are not included into the HTML you're getting. The table you're looking for is not shown until "Show team pitchin" button is pressed, to do this you could use Selenium and get the full HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

**That is because the table you are looking for - *i.e. `<table>` with `id="team_pitching"` is present as a comment inside the soup.*** You can check it for yourself by printing `soup`.

You need to

- Extract that comment from the soup
- Convert it into a soup object
- Extract the table data from the soup object.

Here is the complete code that does the above mentioned steps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import requests

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=17cdc2d2'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

main_div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'all_team_pitching'})

# Extracting the comment from the above selected <div>
for comments in main_div.find_all(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, Comment)):
    temp = comments.extract()

# Converting the above extracted comment to a soup object
s = BeautifulSoup(temp, 'lxml')
trs = s.find('table', {'id': 'team_pitching'}).find_all('tr')

# Printing the first five entries of the table
for tr in trs[1:5]:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
```

The first 5 entries from the table

```
['1', 'Tyler Ahearn', '21', '1', '0', '1.000', '1.93', '6', '0', '0', '1', '9.1', '8', '5', '2', '0', '4', '14', '0', '0', '0', '42', '1.286', '7.7', '0.0', '3.9', '13.5', '3.50']
['2', 'Jack Anderson', '20', '2', '0', '1.000', '0.79', '4', '1', '0', '0', '11.1', '6', '4', '1', '0', '3', '11', '1', '0', '0', '45', '0.794', '4.8', '0.0', '2.4', '8.7', '3.67']
['3', 'Shane Drohan', '*', '21', '0', '1', '.000', '4.08', '4', '4', '0', '0', '17.2', '15', '12', '8', '0', '11', '27', '1', '0', '2', '82', '1.472', '7.6', '0.0', '5.6', '13.8', '2.45']
['4', 'Conor Grady', '21', '2', '0', '1.000', '3.00', '4', '4', '0', '0', '15.0', '10', '5', '5', '3', '8', '15', '1', '0', '2', '68', '1.200', '6.0', '1.8', '4.8', '9.0', '1.88']
```

Comment: When you say comment in the soup, what do you mean? When I load the 'soup1' I get the output I'd originally copied from the website.

Comment: And one other question for you (as I'm learning beautiful soup functionality)... is there a way to extract the table using the class rather than the id?

Comment: Print the ```soup``` and you'll see the ```<table>``` with ```id=team_pitching``` is present inside comments.

Comment: Yes you can use any attribute. Example: ```soup.find('table', {'class': <class_name>}```  will select the first table with matching ```class_name```.

Comment: Ok thanks Ram. By comments do you mean `<div class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented" id="all_team_pitching">`? I have not seen that sort of comments language used, only ` """ quote blocks"""` or `# comments`.

Comment: And actually, for what it's worth, I am not seeing the line `<table class="sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="team_batting" data-cols-to-freeze=",2">` in the soup. I do see `<table class="sortable stats_table" data-cols-to-freeze=",2" id="team_batting">` - is this a function of the Inspect tool and how the page renders when I am using Chrome vs what code soup automatically pulls?

Comment: That's because of JavaScript. JavaScript is executed when you open in Chrome and that will manipulate the DOM. Whereas by using ```beautifulsoup``` no JS gets executed and so you don't see any DOM changes.